# Replace elements in html with custom react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm wondering what is the best way to replace all  elements in html with a `<CustomImage>` component

the function writeText is called in the render function

```
writeText(innerHTML) {
        // Take raw innerHTML string from props and turn it into actual innerHTML with a placeholder
        let tmp = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
        tmp.body.innerHTML = innerHTML;
        const media_sources_to_replace = ['img'];
        media_sources_to_replace.forEach(tag => {
            let ElArr = tmp.getElementsByTagName(tag);
            if (ElArr.length !== 0) {
                    this.replaceImages(ElArr);
            }
        });
return tmp.body.innerHTML;
}
```

Trying replaceImages as below does not seem to work:

```
replaceImages(elArr) {
        const tmp = elArr
        for (let i=0;i < tmp.length; i++) {
            elArr[i] = <CustomImage alt={tmp[i].alt} imgSrc={tmp[i].src}/>
        }
    }
```

My understanding is that you can't edit `HTMLCollection` but I'm unsure what would then be the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit HTMLCollections, that's not the problem. The problem is that JSX code is not any HTML elements. To do this, you would use this:

```js
ReactDOM.render(<CustomImage alt={tmp[i].alt} imgSrc={tmp[i].src} />, elArr[i]);
```

If that doesn't work, add this line before it:

```js
elArr[i].innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: it should be flipped shouldn't it? Custom image first, then the element?

Comment: Yes, I put it the wrong way accidentally. I edited the post.